# Not getting json rest response in my AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, http

This has been frustrating me a bit. I have a restful services giving JSON data running on the link:
http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/

So its running locally on my computer. I can get the data from this service with no problem using my WPF based interface.

Another service I am testing with is this one:
http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting

But from my own service something seems to go wrong somehow and I cannot figure out what goes wrong. I have even tried just taking the full response and printing it. With the second service, I get a long list of data regarding the response, but with my own I still get nothing. As if the function was not used at all.

This is my Angular code:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
    .controller('Hello', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:51133/api/salessystem/').
            //http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting 
            //http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/
            then(function (response) {
                $scope.hello = 'hello';
                $scope.district = response;
            });
    });
```

and this is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <li>Id: <button>{{hello}}</button></li>
        <li>Area: {{district}}</li>
        <ul ng-repeat="obj in hello">
            <li>Area: {{obj.area}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>The ID is {{hello.Id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{hello.Area}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see the problem? The spring rest service shows all kinds of data about the response and it also shows the button with "hello" inside it. But when I use my own service link it seems there is no $scope returned at all.

Oh, and this is the json returned when I just visit the link directly in the browser: (its an array of 3 districts)

```
[{"Id":1,"Area":"North Denmark","PrimarySalespersonID":1,"PrimarySalesperson":{"Id":1,"Name":"Tom B. Erichsen"},"SecondarySalespersons":null,"Stores":null},{"Id":2,"Area":"Southern Denmark","PrimarySalespersonID":2,"PrimarySalesperson":{"Id":2,"Name":"Eric B. Thomsen"},"SecondarySalespersons":null,"Stores":null},{"Id":3,"Area":"Eastern Denmark","PrimarySalespersonID":3,"PrimarySalesperson":{"Id":3,"Name":"Ben Anderson"},"SecondarySalespersons":null,"Stores":null}]
```

Comment: You should add an error function to your get; one, for better error handling but two, to help debug this issue.

Comment: Include an error callback with `$http.get(url).then((response) => {...}, (error) => {...});`

Comment: Ahh, that should help, yes. Thanks :)

Comment: That took a lot of debugging... seems when it uses my service it runs success rather than response.

Comment: I finally found a way to get the error data even though it for some reason uses the success function, the data says data null and status -1.

I will try making a new question regarding this development.