# AngularJS getting strange response from using get on json rest service with no data

Tags: angularjs, json, rest

This has been frustrating me a bit. I have a restful services giving JSON data running on the link: http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/

So its running locally on my computer. I can get the data from this service with no problem using my WPF based interface.

Another service I am testing with is this one: http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting

But from my own service something seems to go wrong somehow and I cannot figure out what goes wrong. The spring service gives me a response using a response function, but my service gives a response using a success function function. Very confusing.

Response seems to be:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}
```

I looked it up and it seemed I might be needed to enable Cors, but I am not entirely sure how. I installed it from NuGet, the service is running with Visual Studio, and I added config.EnableCors(); to my WebApiConfig.

My JS script:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
    .controller('Hello', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/')
            //http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting
            //http://localhost:51133/API/SalesSystem/
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.hello = 'hello';
                $scope.district = response.data;
                console.debug(response.data);
                console.log(response.data)
            }, function success(response) {
                $scope.hello = 'hello2';
                $scope.district = response;
                $scope.rep = response.data;
                console.debug(response.data[0]);
                $scope.district = response.data[0];
                console.log(success.data)
            }, function error(response) {
                $scope.hello = 'hello3';
                $scope.district = error.data;
                console.log(error.data)
            });
    });
```

My html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <li>Id: <button>{{hello}}</button></li>
        <li>Area: {{district}}</li>
        <ul ng-repeat="obj in hello">
            <li>Area: {{obj.area}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>The ID is {{rep.Id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{hello.Area}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting it all to work with my WPF based frontend using this service, not sure why it wont work with AngularJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not getting json rest response in my AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958146/not-getting-json-rest-response-in-my-angularjs-application)

Answer (score 1):

The CORS issue  has nothing to do with angular. It  has got more to do with the browser .

In layman terms , the cors situation is where the browser does not allow responses of other origins than the url to be processed unless the response has a certain set of headers .Of course, it is a bit more complicated than that .Since the response does not have those headers you are getting the CORS issue

For a quick fix you can disable CORS in your browser .

for example :- if you are using   chrome you can run it --disable-web-security flag

Comment: But if it is a CORS issue, would it then affect one REST service (my own) but not another?

Comment: When I use the same service with my WPF UI, it has no problems using the data... but I guess it also does not use the service since it is not browser based... hmm, I guess that might be it. Although when I use http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting to also get JSON from a REST service, it works fine in the same browser.

Comment: Tried it, and I get the same response with CORS disabled.